# How can we implement Role based access control in okta for .net core web application

Tags: asp.net-core, okta

I am able to implement the Authentication using the okta in .net core 2.0 application by using the okta.AspNetCore package . but I am not able to figure out, how to approach for role based authentication here.
Ref link:https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-into-web-app/aspnet/before-you-begin/

Answer (score 1):

At a high-level, you need to do two things:

1. Create a [claims transformer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iclaimstransformation?view=aspnetcore-5.0) that maps your Okta groups to roles so ASP.NET recognizes your Okta groups as roles.
2. Add [Authorize(Roles = "Your Role")] decorators to your endpoints

Okta has published a step-by-step guide that provides much more detail on to how to get it working here:

- https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/10/04/aspnet-authorization